# How to let user add multiple sub-content fields in the main content?

Tags: 7, users, entities, organic-groups

If I want user to create a main content which can be able to add multiple sub-content for example
I wanna do apartment renting website. User have to create the apartment details which contain these fields; Title, Description, Address, Facilities etc.
As 1 apartment usually have multiple different units, user have to add their available units in the apartment node which contain fields; Unit title, room size, bedroom, bathroom, price. And they can add many units as they want.
The question is
 what module should I use? Can I use Organic Group module or something simpler then that?

I'm new for Drupal, learn by myself from scratch, anyone please point me the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If apartment is one content type, and unit is another content type, you can use [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to reference units in apartments. You will create in apartment content type - entityreference field with unlimited values, type of referenced entity would be unit content type - user will be able then to add as many units to his apartment as he wants.

You can even create a view of entity reference display, and use it for selection of available options in your entityreference field.

http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/entityreference-multiselectors - also something about multiselector widgets for entityreference field.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thank you so much for your help. This is what i'm really looking for. :D

Answer (score 0):

I just had a try multi selects module today but it not actually what I want. So I found a solution using field collection module to add a collection of field by set to unlimited value. :)